# ¿Se puede hacer un select dentro de un like? si no, ¿Cómo se haría entonces?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy en el tema de un filtro en el que tiene que buscar por 2 Tablas con relación `N->1` o varias propiedades solo pueden pertenecer a 1 solo propietario, voy al grano

En `PHP` tengo esto

```
SELECT * from cli_propiedades where status<66  AND estado=1 AND (codigo_propiedad like  '".$input['clave']."%' OR localidad like  '".$input['clave']."%' OR direccion like '".$input['clave']."%' OR cp like  '".$input['clave']."%') order by id
```

lo que necesitaria ahora seria algo parecido a esto:

`<consulta anterior>`   `LIKE'%(SELECT * cli_clientes where nombre LIKE '%".$input['clave']."%')%'`

Se podría hacer de esa manera?, si no es así, ¿cuál seria la forma correcta?

Comment: Yo creo que esa sintaxis va a dar error. Me da que meter un select dentro de comillas no es buena idea ya que igual lo interpresa como una cadena literal. Tendrías que sacarlo fuera de comillas. Lo que no sé es si se puede hacer la concatenación tal cual, metiendo el select en medio de '%'. (select...) .'%'. Puede que con una función de concateniación sea posible.
Si tu gestor de base de datos cuenta con la función CONCAT prueba con ella. Debería ser facil de usar.

Comment: lo estoy probando directamente en la BBDD y no funciona ahora estoy probando esto `SELECT * from cli_propiedades where status<66  AND estado=1 OR (SELECT nombre from cli_clientes where nombre like '%as%')` y me dice que devuelve mas de una columna que hago?

Comment: Claro. Usando '%as%' te puede devolver varios resultados. No sé si funcionará pero prueba con OR nombre_campo in (SELECT... etc). Todo es probar, así se aprende mucho. Si tuviera una respuesta clara la publicaría como respuesta. Si no funciona dilo y esperemos que alguien pueda resolverlo.

Comment: la cosa es que el nombre del campo está en la otra tabla, y tengo que hacer la consulta primero de las propiedades y ya despues del el nombre del cliente, no sé si me explico, tambien si le añado un `LIMIT 1 ` al final de la sub consulta funciona jaja

Comment: @juank ¿como se relacionan las tablas `cli_propiedades` y `cli_clientes`? es decir, ¿cual es el campo en `cli_propiedades` que indica a que `cli_clientes` pertenece?

Comment: Alguna novedad?

Comment: en teoria se deberia haber relacionado con un id_cliente en el tabla propiedades, pero tal y como se programó esta con codigo cliente, (no puedo rediseñarlo ya que no estoy autorizado), y gracias a todos por la ayuda llevo semanas con esto

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver la estructura de ambas tablas es complicado, pero algo así debería servirte para acceder a las filas que tengan esas condiciones:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM cli_propiedades
JOIN cli_clientes ON cli_clientes.nombre LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%' AND (cli_propiedades.codigo_propiedad LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%' OR cli_propiedades.localidad LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%' OR cli_propiedades.direccion LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%' OR cli_propiedades.cp LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%')
WHERE cli_propiedades.status < 66
AND cli_propiedades.estado = 1;
ORDER BY cli_propiedades.id";

?>
```

Si el campo *nombre* de **cli_clientes** debiese ser exactamente igual que la coincidencia con uno de los campos *codigo_propiedad*, *localidad*, *direccion* o *cp* de **cli_propiedades**, la consulta podría simplificarse un poco más:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM cli_propiedades
JOIN cli_clientes ON cli_clientes.nombre IN (cli_propiedades.codigo_propiedad, cli_propiedades.localidad, cli_propiedades.direccion, cli_propiedades.cp)
WHERE cli_clientes.nombre LIKE '" . $input['clave'] . "%'
AND cli_propiedades.status < 66
AND cli_propiedades.estado = 1;
ORDER BY cli_propiedades.id";

?>
```

Comment: necesito quie busque por, codigo_ propiedad, localidad, direcciion, cp, y la complicacion esta por nombre de cliente ya que se encuentra en una tabla relacionada

Comment: La primera consulta que he puesto debería hacer lo que comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la siguiente consulta. Recuerda ajustar los campos a los de tu tabla porque no sé si los nombres son exactamente los mismos, no hagas un copia-pega sin cambiar nada según tus tablas, sino no funcionará.

```
SELECT cli_propiedades.*
from cli_propiedades
WHERE status<66
AND estado=1
AND (codigo_propiedad like '".$input['clave']."%'
OR localidad like '".$input['clave']."%'
OR direccion like '".$input['clave']."%'
OR cp like  '".$input['clave']."%') 
OR cli_propiedades.codigo_pripiedad IN
   (SELECT codigo_propiedad
   FROM cli_clientes
   WHERE nombre_cliente LIKE '%as%')
order by id
```

Algo así quizás también, aunque no lo he podido probar. Pero para que te hagas una idea de por donde van los tiros. Además como dice el compañero en la respuesta de arriba, sin conocer la estructura (claves primarias y foraneas) es complicado saber como hay que unir las tablas.
Tampoco tengo claro que información quieres mostrar.

Comment: voy informando voy a probar a cambiar el `LIKE '%as%'` por `LIKE '%".$input['clave']."%'` ,para ver si funciona, espero que si

Comment: Si, eso en cuanto a sintaxis debería ser válido por si solo.